# Google+ Integration in Android PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, google-plus

I was trying to integrate Google+ in my phone Gap application, like twitter and facebook. But, I haven't find out any samples and Tutorials. If any one aware about that, please suggest me, how to do that in android Phone Gap.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a PhoneGap plugin that wraps over the Google+ APIs in Google Play Services.

For more information about the Google+ APIs in Google Play Services, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/